# NS_ERROR_FAILURE for firefox via iframes

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, iframe

So here's the situation. I get the NS_ERROR_FAILURE only on firefox (working on Chrome and Safari). I'm also using Bootstrap with tabs and it's basically erroring on the tabs that aren't displayed initially (so erroring on the hidden tabs), otherwise it works fine. It also errors on the iframes if they are `display: none` at the beginning, however I can `display: none` them after and make them reappear without the error showing up.

Any idea how to get around this?